# inserting and iterating in nested STL map

Tags: c++, oop, vector, dictionary, stl

Modified: Made the code more readable

I recently posted a question about nested STL map however I didn't put any code so I am asking the same question again (this time with the code included). Any help will be greatly appreciated and apologies for spamming.

I am stuck at something for last 4 days and now I am in need of guidance.

Here are my data structures:

```
class demo1
{
    int a, b, c, d, e;
}

class demo2
{
    map(int, demo1) map1
}

map(string, demo2) map2;

vector< pair<int, demo1> > vec1;
```

Now, lets say I have 2 string variables (in "key" of map2) and 3 int variables (in "key" of map1), how do I establish correct mapping between map2 and map1

Here is the output that I am expecting:

```
// Expected mapping output
string 1(key in map2)
int 1(key in map1) -> demo1
int2               -> demo1
int 3              -> demo1
string 2
int 1(key in map1) -> demo1
int2               -> demo1
int 3              -> demo1
```

Here is the relevant portion of the code (Data structures described above are in a header file and here is the main .cpp file in which I use them. Actual code is very long and I am only inserting relevant portion of it)

```
class tmp1
{
    int a, b, c, d e;
} t1;

....

if(condition is true)
{
    string tmp_string // this string is a key in map2
    map2.insert(make_pair(tmp_string, demo2));
}

if(another condition is true)
{
    int n; // this is a "key" in map1
    demo 1 d1 // create an instance of class demo1
    d1.a =  t1.a;
    d1.b =  t1.b;
    d1.c =   t1.c;
    d1. d =   t1.e;
    d1.f  = t1.f;
    // Insert these value into map now
    map1.insert(make_pair(n, d1));
    vec1.push_back(make_pair(n, d1));  // vec1 is define above in the data structure section
}
```

Here is how I am checking for the output

```
map(string, demo2)::iterator outer_itr;
map(int, demo1)::iterator inner_itr;

for(outer_itr = map2.begin(); outer_itr != map2.end(); outer_itr++)
{
    cout << "String is " << (*outer_itr).first << endl;
    vector < pair<int, demo1> >::iterator itr;
    for(itr = vec1.begin(); itr != vec1.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << "Int key in map1 is " << (*itr).first           << endl;
        cout << "Value of a is      " << (*itr).second.second.a << endl;
        cout << "Value of b is      " << (*itr).second.second.b << endl;
        cout << "Value of c is      " << (*itr).second.second.c << endl;
    }
}
```

Is this a right way of doing mapping..?

Comment: Could you please make it readable ? Select all code and press `Ctrl+K`, and of course don't forget to align.

Comment: (*itr).second is of type demo1, not pair. Besides - you still haven't answered - do you intend to keep a demo1 struct for each pair of (string, number in vec1)?

Comment: @Leeor: Yes. I do intend to keep demo1 struct however, vec1 vector is basically a pairing of int and demo1. So for each value of int, will have an associate demo1 class and hence pair. However, as you can see in map2, I want to map string -> (pair(int, demo1)) so for each string value will have associated int values and each int value will have associated values of variables described in demo1.

Comment: Ok, so you have 2 completely independent data structures leading into different demo1 structs. Are the numbers unique? Can you have a number n associated with one struct through vec1, and also some string s associated with the same n and another struct? Do you expect the structs to be identical?

Comment: @Leeor: The numbers (i.e. int n in the example) are unique however, number n is associated with demo1 and string s is associated with both (number n and demo1). Here is how it is: ( string s ->( int n -> demo1)). Values in demo1 class (i.e. a,b,c,d,e) are same for each string S and int n. (In other words, I will have different values of n associated with same values of variables in demo1). Hope I am clear enough

Comment: So you have serious duplication, which can also lead to maintenance bugs. You copy the struct into vec1, and also into the map2 struct (mapped by string and then in the internal map1 hash by the number), right?  Also, how is n unique if different strings can map it internally to different structs (and if they don't and each string maps all numbers to the same demo1 in it's internal map1, then the duplication is even worse...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting and iterating from nested STL map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011782/inserting-and-iterating-from-nested-stl-map)

Comment: @user2812535: You should have edited your old question so it could be opened again.

Comment: @Benjamin Bannier: I did edited my old question however it was put on hold so I had to re-post it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading *I think* your code is simply using demo2 as a map, and as mentioned by @Leeor you are duplicating the map functionality with `vec1` but this is actually also happening with `demo2`. So your final solution should eliminate `vec1` and `demo2`.

There are two ways you could accomplish this:

#### If you want to be able to index directly into a `demo1`, so in your code you would be doing `map2["string 1"].map1[1]` then you need to consolidate your keys

- So your container would look like this: `std::map< std::pair<
  std::string, int >, demo1 > map2`
- Indexing would look like this: map2[std::make_pair("string 1", 1)]

#### If you want to be able to iterate through all values attached to "string 1", so what your code appears to be doing in the for block then you need to use a multimap

- So your container would look like this: `std::multimap< std::string, std::pair< int, demo1 > > map2`
- Inserting would look like this: `map2.insert( std::make_pair( 1, myDemo1 )`
- You would get back a `std::pair` of iterators with the `first` being the begin iterator and the `second` being the end iterator like this: `auto itr = map2.equal_range( "string 1" )`

#### If you need both of the above capabilities you need a nested map as mentioned by @jrok